# Understanding this T Flip-Flop example?

Tags: vhdl

I'm reading a VHDL book and having trouble understanding an example they gave.

The code given:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- RET T Flip-flop model with active-low asynchronous set input. --
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- library declaration
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
-- entity
entity t_ff_s is
  port ( T,S,CLK : in std_logic;
  Q : out std_logic);
end t_ff_s;
-- entity
architecture my_t_ff_s of t_ff_s is
  signal t_tmp : std_logic; -- intermediate signal declaration
begin
  tff: process (S,CLK)
  begin
    if (S = '0') then
      Q <= '1';
    elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then
      t_tmp <= T XOR t_tmp; -- temp output assignment
    end if;
  end process tff;
  Q <= t_tmp; -- final output assignment
end my_t_ff_s;
```

What I don't understand is how they assign multiple signals to Q. Outside of the process statement, it's `Q <= t_tmp` but inside the process if `S='0'` then `Q <= '1'`. How exactly does this work? It looks wrong to me with my limited understanding of VHDL. Basically, this looks the same to me as if writing:

```
Q <= '0';
Q <= '1';
```

Can anyone help me better understand this example better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right to question the example. It's broken.

```
Q <= '1';
```

should be

```
t_tmp <= '1';
```

Somebody realised they couldn't read an output, introduced t_tmp and only changed half the code.

Comment: This is what I thought also, but I wasn't completely sure

Comment: Noted it to the author, and he said this is correct as well and it'll be fixed when he uploads a new version of his book as well